# Firefox addon: input type=“color” closing addon popup on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox-addon

First of all sorry that this is the third time I am posting this question. I got some rude and unhelpful replies the previous times, possible as a result of not being clear enough. I hope this new format will make my actual issue more clear, and hopefully someone knows how to resolve this issue!

So what is the issue? `<input type="color">` inside the the addon popup you get when clicking the extension icon in the toolbar closes said popup (while still providing the color picker). This issue only happens on Firefox, on Chrome using the same extension the color picker opens and the extension popup remains open as it should.

It might also be relevant that I am using Windows. I have not tested this on Linux and MacOS, so it might work as intended on those. But even if those don't have the same issue I would still like the extension to function with this input on all OS's.

This is what said popup looks like (for the example code below):

[image: The popup with the color input element that closes when the color picker is clicked.]

Here is the example code you need to reproduce the issue:
HTML (popup.html):

```
<input type="color">
```

(Adding doctype, html or body tags do not change the behaviour in this case)

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "example",
  "version": "0.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon48.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Title"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/icon128.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "16": "icons/icon16.png"
  }
}
```

You will likely also need to add the folder of icons defined in the manifest to the folder the manifest.json and popup.html are located in. Also if any more info is needed don't hesitate to ask!

For easier testing here is a download to the example extension code given above that reproduces this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ScHxir4jW4cdNSVZmtaNiKiGRTGzGyoH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a serious problem, why no answer in 4 months

Comment: I filed a bug for this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1676222

Comment: I can confirm the same issue exists on Ubuntu 20.04